# What are good synonyms to "not to speak of"?

Tags: synonyms

I wanted to use some other phrase for "not to speak of". What could be a good synonym for that? For example,

> "international community" is a political contrivance; it doesn't exist! And what doesn't exist cannot act, not to speak of influencing Russia's policy.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the context where it would be used?

Comment: I added an example context where it occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest **"not to mention"** or **"to say nothing of"** which sound more common to my ears.

e.g.

- "I don't think it's worth visiting it, not to mention the cost of the trip."
- "They own a magnificent mansion at the Cape. To say nothing of their bank account."

Comment: Sure, that's the first one which comes to my mind as well. But as a non-native English speaker I would like to know more versions of this phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Is this useful?

> And what doesn't exist, cannot act, not to speak of inlfuencing Russia's policy.
>
> And what doesn't exist[,] cannot act, let alone influence Russia's policy.
>
> And what doesn't exist cannot act; even less can it influence Russia's policy.

Comment: Ooh, that's a good one, Hugh. Good for me to keep it in memory, that is. Thank you. Sorry, could not upvote it yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Canadian construct that uses "little say" to mean the same thing. I first noticed it in the writing of Charles De Lint.